# Compiling Production Assets Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am deploying a simple CMS system I built using the Monologue Framework. I have mounted the engine and added by own custom Controllers and Models, such as Pages and Templates.

Whenever I deploy the app to Heroku(or compile assets locally), it fails and gives me this error:

```
    I, [2016-05-13T23:45:15.189577 #31757]  INFO -- : Writing /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/assets/monologue/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker-b6d82843a72ae20b71775b201958ed7dc6bc437a71c554b94c20805cea49b2ad.css.gz
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pages" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"pages"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"pages"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I have no special settings for Assets inside the application.rb or production.rb files. I've declared some assets to be precompiled in assets.rb, but removing these assets don't change anything.

At one point, I did use ActiveRecord Page Caching, but I no longer needed it and due to conflicts with the Page model I removed it.

I've also created a new rails app and deployed it to heroku, with the Monologue engine mounted. The app will precompile all assets and deploy with no issue.

If more files or details are needed, please let me know and I'll add them here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that in one of the assets(admin.js.erb), the file called on `<%= @page.each do |page| %>`, but the database was not created or migrated. I just add in the asset once Heroku is finished compiling assets, and re-deploy.